# Форматирование результата SQL запроса python aiogram

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram, aiogram

Пишу своего бота на `aiogram`.
Для вывода истории пополнения счета пользователя использую данный запрос:

```
def get_paymenthistory(self, user_id):
    with self.connection:
        result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT payed, date FROM paymenthistory WHERE user_id = ?", (user_id,)).fetchall()
        if result is not None:
            return result 
        else:
            return 'вы еще не пополняли свой баланс'
```

При нескольких значениях я получаю:
[(200, '2022-11-29 10:20:11'), (100, '2022-11-29 12:20:20')]

Как мне форматировать этот результат с переносом каждой строки в новую?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Результатом функции get_paymenthistory является массив. Когда его получил – пройдись по ним через for:

```
print("Ваша история пополнения:")

for payment in result:
    print(f"Сумма – {payment[0]} руб., Дата – {payment[1]}.")
```

Comment: Точнее – массив в массиве. Т.е. там будет: payment[0][0], payment[0][1] и т.п.